# Trying to deploy the project, but the data is not fetching from database

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, postman

I'm a beginner and I'm facing some issues with the process. Could you help me ?

So I tried to deploy a nodejs API on digitalOcean .I will explain all the process what I did .

1. I cloned the git to ssh
2. npm installed it,and try to run it on the ssh it self and it worked perfectly and I checked on the domain ip http://165.22.**.**:3003/v1/users and it provided all the users list .
3. then I installed the pm2 globally
4. and then I started the project using pm2 start ....
   and checked on pm2 log for any issue, it shows as  " Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "routes"  .....    | Database Configured
   till then everything looks good.
   but when I go to the link http://165.22.**.**:3003/v1/users ,it does not provide any output ,but on pm2 log the query getting  Executing (default): SELECT "userId", "user_category",

Donot know what i'm doing wrong in this case.

I'm using Ec2 .

Comment: You might missed service call with await.

Comment: @AshishSharma- hi the thing is that it is getting through the try catch block and catching the error response as output, but when running locally the data getting fetched .However when running through domain IP it doesn't